# Emacs keybinding for switching tab via number

Tags: init-file, tabbar

In Emacs 27.1, using `tabbar`. Trying to switch to tabs using numbers. Editing `~/.emacs` with following lines doesn't switch tabs using `C-1`. Produces `C-u 1` and so on. What is missing here? Any other comfortable option?

```
(require 'tabbar)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-1") 'tab-bar-select-tab 1) ; move to 1st tab
(global-set-key (kbd "C-2") 'tab-bar-select-tab 2) ; move to 2nd tab
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global-set-key` doesn't take 3 arguments.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-1") (lambda () (interactive) (tab-bar-select-tab 1)))
```

Or better yet:

```lisp
(defun move-to-first-tab ()
  "Move to first tab."
  (interactive)
  (tab-bar-select-tab 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-1") 'move-to-first-tab)
```

Comment: Thank you for info, and resolution.